# Limiting copas to a particular domain name: Allowing multiple web servers

Tags: sockets, lua

I'm trying to limit the domain name in which copas receives sockets, with the end goal of allowing other web servers to handle requests with other domain names on the same machine. In this particular case, when I use

```
copas.addserver(assert(socket.bind("*", 80)),
    function(c)
        return handler(copas.wrap(c), c:getpeername())
    end
)
```

It correctly handles the request and returns a response as expected. However, when I replace `"*"` with `"localhost"`, my results are mixed. Is this the correct way to go about listening for sockets with a specific domain name (obviously substituting the preferred name in place of localhost)? Will this allow for other web servers to serve content alongside it for other domain names?

**Edit:** It appears that it is working, but will accept any sockets based on IP, not DNS name. Does this mean that I will need multiple IPs to serve multiple DNS names?

Comment: As far as I can tell, copas is IP based in filtering sockets. I ended up going with nginx as a reverse proxy as my solution. Works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at [Xavante](http://keplerproject.github.com/xavante/) which is a webserver from the Kepler project. It does support virtual hosts, so it might be what you're looking for.